# "Bad" Fourier Series derivation

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f(\theta)$ $2\pi$-periodic such that $f(\theta)=e^{\theta}$ for $-\pi<0<\pi$, and $$e^{\theta}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_{n}e^{in\theta}\,\,\, \mathrm{for}\,\, |\theta|<\pi $$
it's  Fourier series. If we formally differentiate this equation, we obtain

$$e^{\theta}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}inc_{n}e^{in\theta}. $$

But this implies  $c_{n}=inc_{n}$ or $(1-in)c_{n}=0$, so, $c_{n}=0\,\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$. This is obviously wrong.

Where is the mistake?

The only thing that I could contest is the derivative of $f$. I know a theorem saying that a *sufficient* condition is $f$ continuous and piecewise smooth, and $f$ is not continous. But it don't implies that I can't derivate term by term.

Comment: @Driver8 Uniform convergence is a sufficient condition, not a necessary one.  The series obtained by differentiating under the summation does not converge.  Hence, the interchange is not legitimate.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I will delete my (dumb) comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $c_n=\frac{\sinh(\pi)}{\pi}\frac{(-1)^n}{1-in}$ and the Fourier series for $e^\theta$ on $-\pi<\theta<\pi$ is

$$e^\theta =\frac{\sinh(\pi)}{\pi}\sum_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{1-in}\,e^{in\theta}$$

Clearly, the series $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty inc_ne^{in\theta}=\frac{\sinh(\pi)}{\pi}\sum_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\,in}{1-in}\,e^{in\theta}$, which is obtained by formal differentiation under the summation, is divergent.  Hence, differentiation under the summation is illegitimate and does not lead to a Fourier series representation of $e^\theta$ for $-\pi<\theta<\pi$.

---

---

EDIT:

We may derive the derivative of the Fourier series representation of $e^{\theta}$ for $\theta\in (-\pi,\pi)$.  Proceeding we have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{1-in}e^{in\theta}&=1+\sum_{n\ne0}\frac{(-1)^n}{1-in}e^{in\theta}\\\\
&=1+\sum_{n\ne0}\frac{(-1)^n(in-1+1)}{(1-in)(in)}e^{in\theta}\\\\
&=1+\sum_{n\ne0}\frac{(-1)^n}{in}e^{in\theta}+\sum_{n\ne0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(1-in)(in)}e^{in\theta}
\end{align}$$

We may differentiate the second series under the summation to obtain

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{d\theta}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{1-in}e^{in\theta}
&=\underbrace{\frac{d}{d\theta}\sum_{n\ne0}\frac{(-1)^n}{in}e^{in\theta}}_{=1}+\sum_{n\ne0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(1-in)}e^{in\theta}\\\\
&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{1-in}e^{in\theta}
\end{align}$$

So, we have shown that the derivative of the Fourier series $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{1-in}e^{in\theta}$ for $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi)$ is in fact itself.  This is no surprise since $\frac{d}{d\theta}e^\theta=e^\theta$.

Comment: Why was this answer down voted??

Comment: Mark, your answer is good actually. I gave you 1+

Comment: Thank you Mateus.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You have to think in terms of distributional derivatives, because in this sense you can switch series and derivative. Think $f$ as defined on the 1-torus. Then the distributional derivative of $f$ it is not $f$ itself, but $f-(e^\pi-e^{-\pi})\delta_{[\pi]}$, where $\delta_{[\pi]}$ is the delta Dirac in the point $[\pi]$ of the 1-torus. So, in distributional sense: $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty inc_ne_n = f'=f-(e^\pi-e^{-\pi})\delta_{[\pi]}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_ne_n - (e^\pi-e^{-\pi})\delta_{[\pi]}$$
i.e.:
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (in-1)c_ne_n=-(e^\pi-e^{-\pi})\delta_{[\pi]}=-(e^\pi-e^{-\pi})\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{in\pi}e_n \\ = -(e^\pi-e^{-\pi})\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2\pi}e_n.$$
Then:
$$\forall n\in \mathbb{Z}, (in-1)c_n=-\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2\pi}(e^\pi-e^{-\pi})$$
i.e.:
$$\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}, c_n=\frac{(-1)^{n}(e^\pi-e^{-\pi})}{2\pi(1-in)}.$$

Comment: The series $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}inc_ne^{in\theta}$ diverges.

Comment: @MarkViola not in distributional sense: check Gel'fand - Shilov, generalized functions, vol. 1

Comment: @MarkViola I already gave you a reference

Comment: Chapter 1, pag.30, example 2.: "any series of the form $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n e^{inx}$ whose coefficients increas no faster than some power of $n$ as $|n|\rightarrow\infty$ converges in the sense of generalized functions"

Comment: I understand this, but I was not under the impression that the question in the OP was asked broadly in the sense of generalized functions, but rather classical analysis only.

Comment: @MarkViola it is unpolite to delete your comments and try to change how you developed the discussion. Anyway, as you can see, the answer explain the reason of the appearent discrepancy and, as you can see, op is satisfied by the answer.

Comment: Bob, there is no such word as "unpolite."  The word you probably meant is "impolite."  And I disagree that my deleting my comments is impolite.  Rather, my deleted comments were clutter, in my opinion.  Hence, to clean up the noise, I deleted the comments.  Finally, the only tags that are in the OP are "sequences and series," "Fourier analysis," and "Fourier series."  Inasmuch as there was no tag on distributions, I was under the impression that the context of the question was in the setting of classical analysis.  My post addresses the question from that perspective.

Comment: @Bob The Fourier coefficients for the Dirac comb should be $(-1)^n/(2 \pi)$.

Comment: The function $f(\theta)=\sum_{n}\frac{(-1)^n}{1-in}e^{in\theta}$, $\theta\in (-\pi,\pi)$ is differentiable with derivative equal to $f(\theta)$.  There is no need to invoke the theory of distributions.  And in fact, it is only relevant if one extends the domain.